# Symfony - retreive unmapped fields in nested forms

Tags: php, symfony, formbuilder

I'm having a Symfony Type `ItemType` which is based on an Entity.

```
class IpQuoteItemsType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('itemName', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Produktname'
            ])
            ...
            ->add('specialDiscount', PercentType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'label' => 'Sonderrabatt',
                'mapped' => false,
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Sonderrabatt 0,00 %'
                ]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => IpQuoteItems::class
        ));
    }

}
```

Which is used as a CollectionType in the final form:

```
class IpQuotesType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        ...
        $builder->add('products', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => IpQuoteItemsType::class,
            'data' => $items
        ]);
    }

}
```

Under no circumstances I receive the unmapped field `specialDiscount`. It is still available in the PRE_SUBMIT event of the `ItemsType` but can't be found anywhere in the final form `QuotesType`.

Is it possible to sumit unmapped data in nested forms?

Comment: Yes it is, I've just tested in local for Symfony 2.8. Don't know why this is happening to you, could you try dumping the request data at the begining of the controller action and see if it is there?

Comment: Thank you. Weirdly it IS INDEED within the $request, but it seems that `$form->handleRequest($request)` converts the submitted data into Item-Objects and hence looses the unmapped fields. I guess I will pick them out of the request varariable, but it does not seem right ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get unmapped field in your controller like this :

```
$form->get('nestedEntity')->get('fieldName')->getData()
```

I don't test with collection but it's work with a customType in OneToOne relation.

Hope this help.

Comment: You, sir, are an absolute genius and absolutely right. While `$form->getData()` does not get me any results, `$form->get('products')[$arrayIndex]->get('specialDiscount')->getData()` absolutely works like charm. Note that apposed to your solutions, I still need to access the array first of results first!

Answer (score 1):

Also a thank you to @threeside for his solution.
I also use a collection field to embed a subform. In my case it is a FileType field to upload images which have to be unmapped for the processing.

With

```
$subform_data = $form->get('name_of_collection_field')
```

you get the form data (or is it a symfony form object?) of the subform.
In case of a collection field you can iterate over the items with

```
foreach($subform_data as $subform_item) {
            $items[] = $subform_item->get('unmappedFieldName')->getData();
        }
```

to collect the items in the $items array.
The entire trick is to use the form data/object, from that you can extract unmapped fields.