# Extra unmapped field in Collection Type is not retrieved

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I have the following structure :

- An entity "Module"
- An entity "Parameter"

A module could have many parameters.

My test module have a collection of 3 parameters.

Each parameter haven't got the same functional role, it could be a text, an integer, a choice, so, i made a FormType which format the parameter. See below

My ModuleType (embedded a collection of ParametreModuleTestType)

```
class ModuleType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('parametres', CollectionType::class, [
            'label' => false,
            'entry_type' => ParametreModuleTestType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Module::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

My ParametreModuleTestType :

```
class ParametreModuleTestType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $parametre = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();
            switch ($parametre->getPropriete()) {
                case "tempMax":
                    $form
                        ->add('valeur', IntegerType::class, [
                            'label' => false
                        ]);
                    break;
                case "dateRange":
                    $form
                        ->add('valeur', TextType::class, [
                            'label' => false
                        ]);
                    $form
                        ->add('valeurformatted', HiddenType::class, [  //Extra field here, only in specific item parameter
                            'label' => false,
                            'mapped' => false
                        ]);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Parametre::class,
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my controller, after submitted the form :

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ModuleType::class, $module);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    dd($form['valeurformatted']);
```

I have the following error:

> Child "valeurformatted" does not exist.

Of course, my view contain this hidden extra field.

I suppose I can't access to this data with the classic syntax "`$form['fieldname']`" because it's in collection but is there a solution ? Other than nested loop in deep arrays in request submitted?

Comment: to help yourself, try to var_dump `$form->getData();` and see whats inside and how it´s structured

Comment: Why make us read all these extensive details just to ask about showing a hidden form field?? Please simplify your question down to the last few paragraphs. The rest is irrelevant.

Comment: as you correctly noted, the valeurformatted is in a collection and as such can obviously not be accessed via `$form['valeurformatted']`, instead obviously you have to have a look at `$value['parametres']`'s children, each of which *might* contain a valeurformatted element.

Comment: You  may want to look at  this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828994/symfony-retreive-unmapped-fields-in-nested-forms