# How to access unmapped data in embedded forms?

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony4

I've embedded a collection of forms like here: [Embedding a collection of forms. Empty results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631211/embedding-a-collection-of-forms-empty-results)

In my controller, I would like to access (get and set) unmapped fields, like view, new, edit, delete.

How do I do that?

I've tried dumping the form, but I couldn't find the submitted data anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$request->get('formname')['formfield']
```

to get your form values.

Comment: What exactly is my 'formname' in this case?

Comment: That's a good question, you can see your form name inspecting the "name" attribute of your <form> HTML element. 
I can't tell for sure where this name is picked from, but i suppose the default value is given from the FormType.php class, so if you have MyFormType.php class your form name will be(by default) MyForm. At least this is what i noticed checking my projects.

Comment: There's an issue with this approach, I need to access (set) the data (checkboxes) before the view is created and as far as I understand, with your approach, I can only access the data after the view is created, correct? It works in other cases, except I also still have problem with setting the values (getting them works), but it might be because I need to work on it.

Comment: I had it working when there was no collection of forms, because I could access the values with $form[$key]->setData(), but when I changed to embedded forms to have a single submit button, I could no longer use that solution.

Comment: Okay, I've got it working based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828994/symfony-retreive-unmapped-fields-in-nested-forms